# Type error: Type'{ children:Element[];className:string;}'is not assignable to type'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>,HTMLDivEl

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I am using Next js and typescript

In Vs code, I get the error **Type error: Type '{ children: Element[]; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>'.
Property 'className' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>'.**

[image: 1]

I don't know what's making vs code assume I am using nextjs.

I disabled eslint and still get the error. It works when I run the app but it's annoying to see that error in vscode.

what can i do ?

.........................................

Comment: "I am using Next js" => "I am using React.js"  ???

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type of `children` to `React.ReactNode`